# Send String via retrofit to server - Android?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am passing a `string` via `retrofit` to `server` like bellow:

```
private static final String TEST_QUERY = "query{echo(message:\"Hello\")}";
```

but when I get log from server I get the string like bellow :

```
"query{echo(message:\"Hello\")}"
```

But I need to get it like bellow :

```
query{echo(message:"Hello")}
```

Bellow is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private API mApi;
    private static final String TEST_QUERY = "query{echo(message:\"Hello\")}";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createApi();
        mApi = createApi();
        callMe();
    }

    private void callMe() {
        Call<CustomMutation> accountCall = mApi.queryWithCall(TEST_QUERY);
        accountCall.enqueue(new Callback<CustomMutation>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CustomMutation> call, Response<CustomMutation> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    //DataMutation account = response.body();
                    Log.i("AAAAAAAA", "A" + response.body().getData().getEcho() + "");
                } else {
                    Log.i("AAAAAAAA", "B");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CustomMutation> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("AAAAAAAA", "C  " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
        Log.i("AAAAAAAA", accountCall.request().url() + "");
    }

    private API createApi() {
        OkHttpClient ok = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://88.99.132.161/")
                .client(ok)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(API.class);
    }
}
```

And my `Interface` :

```
interface API {
    @POST("graphql/server.php")
    Call<CustomMutation> queryWithCall(@Body String query);
}
```

My libraries is :

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use Scalars Converter:

Add this to your `build.gradle`:

```
compile  'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
```

Your `createApi()` should look like that:

```
private API createApi() {
    OkHttpClient ok = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .build();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://88.99.132.161/")
            .client(ok)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    return retrofit.create(API.class);
}
```